# Dynamically added tailwind classes showing no effect

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, tailwind-css

I am creating a small  website using `tailwindcss` and `webpack` , to add new task you have to click `Add Task`.

Now when you will fill the form and click green `Add` button , a new task div is created  but this div is not respecting any `utility classes` which are being applied over it. All the classes are present there ( you can inspect on the task element ) but showing no effects .

How can I fix this ?
Here is the [website](https://tribhuwan-joshi.github.io/Todo-List/) .
Here is my [code](https://github.com/Tribhuwan-Joshi/Todo-List)

Comment: This is far too general. Please try sharing only the relevant code in a code block.

Comment: Change content section of `tailwind.config.js`, it should include both html and js files

Comment: ok , I will change the config file

Answer (score 0):

```
class="container-addTask w-auto md:w-[82%] mx-10 h-max p-2 hidden  bg-yellow-200 flex-col md:gap-3 rounded-md px-3">
```

i think it should be class="container addTask ...."